# Loop into a JS object to fill a table

Tags: javascript, object

Here the JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/0xae7k2o/

I'm tryin to loop throw the following JS object:

```
124: {"room_id": 124, "room_name": "House #", "room_nights_nb": 1, "room_nights_list": undefined, "room_night_price": "125.00", …}
```

And fill a table.

But it doesn't work as it displayed all the time `undefined`.

Do you know why please ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your key was incorrect, just remove "",

From:

```
    BOO_UnitsList[room_id] = {
        '"room_id"' : room_id,
        '"room_name"' : room_name,
        '"room_nights_nb"' : room_nights_nb,
        '"room_night_price"' : room_night_price,
        '"room_night_total"' : room_night_total
    }
```

To:

```
    BOO_UnitsList[room_id] = {
        'room_id' : room_id,
        'room_name' : room_name,
        'room_nights_nb' : room_nights_nb,
        'room_night_price' : room_night_price,
        'room_night_total' : room_night_total
    }
```